# TinyMCE listboxes and menus stay open after page reopening with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, tinymce

I have my webapplication in which I open some popup pages in a colorbox popup (http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

In one of these popups I have to load a page with my TinyMCE installation, and I've managed to do this.
The problem I'm running into is that when I close the popup with the editor and reopen it for an edit the drop downs and menus remain open, as you can see in the screenshots.

screenshots removed, see below for the screencast

I'm using tiny_mce.js, and everytime the page loads, this function gets executed:

```
function initScriptEditor()
{

    jQuery1_6_2.getJSON("/DeliDete/listTemplateVariables",

            function(result)
            {

                // Creates a new plugin class and a custom listbox
                tinymce
                      .create(
                            'tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin',
                            {
                                createControl : function(n, cm)
                                {

                                    switch(n)
                                    {
                                        case 'variablesMenu':
                                                                                                var total = parseInt(result.size, 10);
                                                var variables = new Array();
                                                for( var i = 0, j = 0; j < total; i += 5, j++)
                                                {
                                                    variables[i] = result.values[j].level;
                                                    variables[i + 1] = result.values[j].group;
                                                    variables[i + 2] = result.values[j].displayed_name;
                                                    variables[i + 3] = result.values[j].name;
                                                    variables[i + 4] = result.values[j].query;
                                                }

                                                var c = cm
                                                      .createMenuButton(
                                                            'variablesListBox',
                                                            {
                                                               title : 'Variabili',
                                                               image : 'javascripts/tiny_mce/template.gif',
                                                               icons : false
                                                            });

                                                c.onRenderMenu
                                                      .add(function(c, m)
                                                      {
                                                          var subMenuArray = new Array();
                                                          var subSubMenuArray = new Array();
                                                          var levels = new Array();
                                                            var groups;
                                                            var template_variables;
                                                            for( var levels_i = 0, levels_j = 0; levels_i < variables.length; levels_i += 5, levels_j++)
                                                            {
                                                                if(!isInArray(levels,variables[levels_i]))
                                                                {
                                                                    groups = new Array();
                                                                    levels[levels_j] = variables[levels_i];
                                                                    // aggiungo menu
                                                                            // livello
                                                                    subMenuArray[levels_j] = m.addMenu(
                                                                {
                                                                    title : levels[levels_j]
                                                                });
                                                                    // aggiungo tutti i
                                                                            // gruppi per quel
                                                                            // livello
                                                                    for( var groups_i = 1, groups_j = 0; groups_i < variables.length + 1; groups_i+=5, groups_j++)
                                                                    {
                                                                        if(variables[groups_i - 1] == levels[levels_j] && !isInArray(groups,variables[groups_i]))
                                                                        {
                                                                            template_variables = new Array();
                                                                            groups[groups_j] = variables[groups_i];
                                                                            // aggiungo menu
                                                                                    // gruppo
                                                                            subSubMenuArray[groups_j] = subMenuArray[levels_j].addMenu(
                                                                          {
                                                                              title : groups[groups_j]
                                                                          });
                                                                            // aggiungo tutte
                                                                                    // le variabili
                                                                                    // per quel
                                                                                    // gruppo
                                                                            for( var variables_i = 2, variables_j = 0; variables_i < variables.length + 2; variables_i+=5, variables_j++)
                                                                            {
                                                                                if(variables[variables_i - 2] == levels[levels_j] && variables[variables_i - 1] == groups[groups_j] && !isInArray(template_variables,variables[variables_i]))
                                                                                {
                                                                                    template_variables[variables_j] = variables[variables_i];
                                                                                    // //aggiungo
                                                                                            // menu
                                                                                            // item
                                                                                            // variabile
                                                                                    subSubMenuArray[groups_j].add(
                                                                                {
                                                                                   title : variables[variables_i],
                                                                                   onclick : function()
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,variables[findValue(variables,this.title)]);
                                                                                   }
                                                                                });
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                      });

                                                return c;

                                     }

                                    return null;
                                }
                            });

                // Register plugin with a short name
                tinymce.PluginManager.add('templatevariables',
                      tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin);

                tinyMCE
                      .init(
                      {
                         language : "it",
                         mode : "exact",
                         elements : "editor_editorText",
                         theme : "advanced",
                         skin : "o2k7",
                         plugins : "-templatevariables,searchreplace,pagebreak,advhr,insertdatetime,preview,print,table,template,paste,autoresize,advlist,contextmenu,inlinepopups,nonbreaking",
                         theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,selectall,|,search,replace,|undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
                         theme_advanced_buttons2 : "outdent,indent,|,image,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,insertdate,inserttime,|,advhr,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,print,|,template,variablesMenu",
                         theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,table,row_props,cell_props,delete_col,delete_row,col_after,col_before,row_after,row_before,split_cells,merge_cells,|,nonbreaking,pagebreak",
                         theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                         theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                         // theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                         paste_block_drop : true,
                         dialog_type : "modal",
                         plugin_insertdate_dateFormat : "%d-%m-%Y",
                         nonbreaking_force_tab : true,
                         pagebreak_separator : "page-break-after: always;"
                      });

                fillTextBoxFromProposte();
            });
}
```

Could the problem be the fact it reloads every time I open the colorbox popup? Sincerely I don't think so, but since I am a newbie in this world, I can't know for sure..
Is there a function that collects all menu items that can be opened and closes them?

Edit: I added a screencast so you can see what's happening

http://screencast.com/t/ZTysWEBaQ

Comment: can you open up a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: What do you mean? Open it in my browser? Please explain your comment. Thanks!

Comment: you can open up a jsfiddle using the form under http://jsfiddle.net/  . Others can follow your problem and even construct a solution.

Comment: Ok now I understand. I didn't know the use of jsfiddle.net. I would like to thank you for your effort, but I think it's too much to load a working example in jsfiddle, because this webapplication is a complex mix of ajax, javascripts, libraries, jsps and luck :D I believe I put all the relevant informations here, but they're far from a running example..

Comment: too bad. the only quick and dirty hack that comes into mind is to close those boxes after the page has been reopened. Something like $(document).ready(){$('#id_to_box').hide();}

Comment: I added a screencast of the problem, so you can see it with your eyes. If anything else comes to your mind, I would be glad to hear it. About your proposed solution, I'm trying to work out every id I need and find a place where to put the function to close every listbox and menu.

Comment: i remeber i had a similar behaviour once and solved it as i described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this bug by inserting:

tinymce.get("editorID").remove();

in my close function of the popup.
I think it was a problem caused by duplicated id for the instances, because they were never destroyed and every time I loaded the page got generated another one.